# Linq where-filter causes cast to base class

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, odata, breeze

I have a generic IQueryable of a concrete class:

```
IQueryable<Person> result = GetAllEmployees(); //returns IQueryable<Employee>
```

If I return `result` in a service-call for a Breeze-Entitytype, everything works fine:

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from("Employees").orderBy("EmployeeID");
```

As soon as I add a where-filter to the `result` in the service-call, the whole IQueryable-Object seems to be casted to the base class `Person` and not have a property `EmployeeID` anymore:

```
IQueryable<Person> result = GetAllEmployees(); //returns IQueryable<Employee>
result = result.Where(o => myHashSet.Contains(o.Id));
```

This causes the following Error:

```
Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException: The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'EmployeeID' on type 'Person'.
```

Comment: And what does your `Person` class look like?

Comment: How do you determine it´s casted at all? of course the *compile-time*-type of `result` is `IQueryable<Person>`, not `IQueryable<Employee>`. So even if `GetAllEmployess` returns instances of `Employee` *at runtime*, this returned collection is stored in a reference of the collection of the base-class.

Comment: @HimBromBeere well I interpret it from the error message - this is a valid point, I'm not able to determine it.

Comment: @Drag0nvil the `Person` class contains properties like Name and Firstname but no `EmployeeID`.

Comment: why not use `IQueryable<Employee>` ?

Comment: What do you think the full type of `Where<>` is when applied to `IQueryable<Person>` ?

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic that would probably work but I cannot in my instance as it is a more generic call to fill a table with objects of a type determined at runtime.

Comment: @NetMage as stated in my answer below: after the `where` - the `ElmentType` of the IQueryable changes from `Employee` to `Person`

Comment: Because of the way you typed `result`.  The return from `Where` is `IQueryable<TSource>` where `TSource` is inferred from the `IQueryable<TSource>` that `Where` is applied to, in this case `result`, so `Where` returns `IQueryable<Person>`, the same type of `result`. If you wanted `result` to be `IQueryable<Employee>`, why not declare it as `IQueryable<Employee>`?

Comment: @NetMage as stated in my reply to Nikola.Lukovic: I cannot declare it as `IQueryable<Employee>` because I don't know the Type at design time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `where` wrapps the `IQueryable` into a new `IQueryable` of the type of the variable it is stored in. The `ElementType` of the original IQueryable is lost.

You can see this when you break at the `where` and inspect `result.ElementType`. As soon as you step over the `where` it changes from `Employee` to `Person`.

With the following Code we restore the ElementType (feed it with `result.ElementType` from before the `where`):

```
public static IQueryable<T> ToTypedQueryable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Type theType, bool exact = false) {
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    System.Collections.IList result = (System.Collections.IList)typeof(List<>)
        .MakeGenericType(theType)
        .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
        .Invoke(null);

    foreach (var s in source) {
        Type t = s.GetType();
        if (t == theType) {
            result.Add(s);
        } else if (!exact && t.IsSubclassOf(theType)) {
            result.Add(s);
        }
    }

    return (IQueryable<T>)(result.AsQueryable());
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference from using the built-in `Cast<T>`?

Comment: @NetMage I just tried it - the difference is: for `Cast<T>` I need to know the Type at design time and for my method, I can pass the Type at run time.